# TelerikReport send null as parameter to StoredProcedure

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I want to use Telerik report in project, and want to use a stored-Procedure as data source. So, I should make a report in Telerik Report Designer in first step (my problem), and then use it in my Asp.net project.
 I exactly used the (wizard) approach to make data source and parameters, mentioned in Telerik documentations, but there is a problem:
The report passes only the default parameter defined on design time, and when I change the parameter value in preview mode, it doesn't be passed to SP. If I set no default value for my parameters, the SP would be call by null values, always. It seems there is no mapping between input textboxes and the parameters are be sent to SP.
Is there anybody had the same experience, that can help  me?
**UPDATE:**
What I did:

- create new blank report in Telerik Report Designer R1 2017
- From Data tab, Select SQL Data Source,select the proper SP from an Existing Data connection, leave the parameters default value empty and then execute...and finish.
- In Report Explorer window, right click on Parameters, and add new parameter with the name and data type of stored procedure parameter. Change it's visibility to true, without any value.
- From Home tab, select the preview and checked the SQL Profiler for db calls tracking. The Sp is called by null values at first time, but even when I change the parameter value in preview mode, again the SP is called by null parameter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In design time, after selecting your SP as data source, you will see the **Configure Data Source Parameters**.
 In this window, you see your SP's parameters with value types.  In **Value** column, click each row and select `<New Report Parameter>` and then select the parameter. The value will be change to proper value, for example:

```
= <Parameters.CustomerNumber.Value>
```

And this will work correctly. The problem was the 3th. step in question above. (adding the parameters, manually)